# Accesing WCF Service behind Firewall from Internet

Tags: wcf, firewall, dmz

We have some WCF Services that are located on the intranet behind firewalls and are only consumed by internal applications.

The new requirement is that few services need to be consumed also from external companies through the internet.

Someone in my company suggest create services in the DMZ with the exact same contract of the services that we need to expose outside the company, the implementation of these DMZ services will be only a call to intranet services. This will solve our problem but i think there are other solutions.

Another suggestions or some network configuration?, Are we missing something obvious?

Best regards

Comment: What are your external authentication and authorization requirements. Are they the same as for your internal hosted services and consumers? Probably not ...

Answer (score 1):

Working on a similar project.  You may need to have your system administrators create a special Active Directory account configured for trust/delegation in order for the WCF service in the DMZ to be able to talk to the web service inside the Firewall.